# How to replicate "ordinary" call syntax for dynamically bound functions?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, scala-2.10, dynamic-binding, luaj

In the example below, the variable `fn2_class` represents a function that is to be loaded from a lua script, hence the `var` definition is necessary; It is not known in compile time what the actual function will be. The variable `fn1_class` represents the statically bound version of the same idea. The only difference between `fn1_class` and `fn2_class` is thus that the former is defined as a value and the latter as a variable.

The method `getFunction` represents how the lua function is loaded. The real code includes calls to the luaj library to generate the function.

**Rephrasing the question with this context in mind:** How to define a variable `fn3_class` that is dynamically bound and has the same call syntax as the value `fn1_class` in the example?

This question touches scala-2.10 or later. This kind of code was compiling and executing in scala-2.9.

#### Example code illustrating the problem:

```
object Class {
    // static binding
    val fn1_class: (String*) => String = getFunction()
    // dynamic binding
    var fn2_class: (String*) => String = null            

    def getFunction(): (String*) => String = {
        val fn_dyn : (String*) => String = x => { x.head }
        fn_dyn
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        fn2_class = getFunction()
        println( fn1_class() )
        println( fn2_class() )
    }   
}
```

The above code generates, when complied, the following error message (scala-2.10).

```
error: not enough arguments for method apply: (v1: String)String in trait Function1.
Unspecified value parameter v1.
            println( fn2_class() )
                              ^
```